# stars package in R. How to add time dimension in a stars object?

Tags: raster, r, time, stack, stars

I have a raster stack (*my_stack*) and I converted it into a stars object:

```
mystar <- st_as_stars(my_stack)
```

That results in:

```
stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s), summary of first 1e+05 cells:
    layer.1        
 Min.   :  0.0000  
 1st Qu.:  0.0000  
 Median :  0.0000  
 Mean   :  0.7897  
 3rd Qu.:  0.0000  
 Max.   :686.6100  
dimension(s):
     from  to  offset delta                       refsys point               values    
x       1 904  104010  1000 +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon...    NA                 NULL [x]
y       1 773 4623806 -1000 +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon...    NA                 NULL [y]
band    1  67      NA    NA                           NA    NA layer.1,...,layer.67
```

I also have a vector with Date objects.
How could I add this vector as time dimension in *mystar* object?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```r
mystar = st_set_dimensions(mystar, 3, values = dates, names = "date")
```

where `dates` is the `Date` vector.

Comment: This will replace 3nd dimension with dates. Will not add new dimension.Right?

Comment: Right. The `st_set_dimensions` function is used to modify the properties of existing dimensions.

Comment: @MichaelDorman what if the `{stars}` object doesn't contain a band yet?

Comment: @CharlieJoeyHadley If there is no dimension `3` (bands) then this expression will not work. Can't set dimension properties on a non-existing dimension.